# Facebook Graph API - Example code of checking if user has liked facebook page with access token authorisation using Javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've looked everywhere to find an example code that checks if the current user has liked a facebook page WITH authorization using access_token.

Here is the code I usually come across which I've tried and still didn't work:

```
FB.api("/me/likes/{page-id}", 'GET', function(response) {

}
```

The output of that code is a json that is empty. How would I add a access_token to get permission of user_likes in a code such as that.

P.S. I've looked at the documentation for graph api and it's quite vague as there isn't any example of you would get authorization to see if a user likes a facebook page using Javascript.

Comment: Like gating is not allowed any more by Facebook. When you send your app in for permission review, they will not grant you the use of `user_likes´ permission for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how, I didn't embed my code in FB.login

```
FB.login(function(){
FB.api(
'/me/likes/{page-id}',
'GET',
function(response) {
  if(response.data.length == 1){
     alert('User has liked page');
  }else{
     alert('User hasn't liked page');
  }
}
);
}, {scope: 'user_likes'});
```